# Why is TLB(Translation look aside buffer) stored in PCB during context switch?

Tags: linux, operating-system, paging, tlb

Why is TLB(Translation look aside buffer) stored in PCB during context switch? Isnt saving page table for the process not enough?

Answer (score -1):

The Translation Look Aside buffer is NOT stored in the Process Context Block. On some processors the TLB has to be flushed as part of the context switch.